# EvalMath undefined function get_string when using namespace

Tags: php

I want to use evalMath on my project.
My project uses autoloader, and every lib project is namespaced.

when I add the class to a namespace I get the following error

```
 Fatal Error: undefined function get_string() on line 211.
```

I looked for this function in the code, it is not defined and it isn't built-in PHP function either.

When I use it without namespaces

```
require_once('EvalMath.php');
$m = new EvalMath();
$m -> evaluate('2+2');
```

It works fine.
Problem is I don't know how does it work with get_string(), if someone else has faced this issue, please tell me how I can solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a modified version of this class. Use the original version, which does not require this function:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html